# Should I use DeleteDC after CreateDC in this case

Tags: c#, winapi

I have the following code

```
public static class GammaRamp
{
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private unsafe static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, ushort* ramp);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string lpszDriver, string lpszDevice, string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);

        private static Int32 hdc;
        //some other things

       public static unsafe void SetGammaRamp(int aBrightness, int aTemperature)
       {
            //...some other things calculating rgbArray but not important for the question

            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                //Get the hardware device context of the screen
                hdc = CreateDC(screen.DeviceName, null, null, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32();
                SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, rgbArray);
            }
       }
}
```

Is it good practice converting CreateDC result to ToInt32 instead keep it IntPtr and then to call DeleteDC.
There is DeleteDC method which I should use after CreateDC but is this necessarily in my code? I hope that this code will not do some kind of memory problems.

Comment: Yes, `SetDeviceGammaRamp` does not take ownership of the device context passed in.

Comment: Required.  First argument of both SetGammaRamp() and DeleteDC() is IntPtr, not Int32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, always call `DeleteDC()` for any device context you create with `CreateDC()` when it is no longer needed, and call `ReleaseDC()` for any device context you obtain via `GetDC()` or `GetWindowDC()`.

I can think of no common situation in which you are not responsible for destroying a DC that you create - as a rule, assume you need to do it, unless documented otherwise.

Comment: Particularly, assume that you need to delete a DC when it's no longer needed, if it is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw) that you need to do this.

Comment: There's this sentence on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw): _"If lpszDriver or lpszDevice is DISPLAY, the thread that calls CreateDC owns the HDC that is created. When this thread is destroyed, the HDC is no longer valid"_. One may think that the system destroys the HDC on thread exit (like HWNDs), but actually it doesn't, you still have to call DeleteDC